# Cannot ssh to the Debian Vm on Azure

Tags: ssh, debian, azure, azure-networking

I have a custom image of **Debian 6** and i have created an **Azure Vm** out of it. I am trying to **ssh** to it but it fails. The port 22 doesn't respond. I see the login screen of the vm from the troubleshooting section so it means that the boot is successfull. I have attached to the VM a Nic with a private&public ip.

I have also tested this local image in my local Hyper-V and i can ssh to it with a static ip address. But i cannot do the same in Azure neither with public nor private ip.

I didn't put any nsg so it is not a nsg problem.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to configure NSG in case you want to access SSH from the internet to your VM, refer to this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#security-rules)

- Azure translates a public IP address to a private IP address for inbound traffic, and before Azure translates a private IP address to a public IP address for outbound traffic.

In other words when creating a NSG rule you always consider your private IP, I mean from the internet to your SSH VM, add its private IP on port 22 for example and source your public internet IP.

Alternately you can investigate it further through console as described into this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/serial-console-linux), you should check SSH service, IP configuration inside VM and so on.

Comment: as stated, there is no nsg. All the ports are open for testing purpose so it is not because of nsg.

Comment: Just in case, go to [Network Watcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview), then run a test to make sure that everything is ok within your Azure network (VNET, NSG and so on). For example Flow IP, NSG rules and even a capture package that you can see if any package from your source is reaching out Azure. You can use console as I mentioned to access your VM, if you are familiar with TCPDUMP, you can also capture package from your source. When you say "there is no NSG",  I assume you mean that you have one and a rule to allow all source.